# Undefined reference to SDL_Init with Qt Creator

Tags: windows, qt, sdl, sdl-2

I'm trying to build the following basic SDL2 application with *Qt Creator* (*Qt 5.1.1*).

**SDLTest.pro :**

```
TARGET = SDLTest01
CONFIG   += console

TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += C:\Users\Martin\code\libs\SDL2-2.0.1\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include
LIBS += -LC:\Users\Martin\code\libs\SDL2-2.0.1\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib -lSDL2

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

**main.cpp :**

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#include <QCoreApplication>
#undef main
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING ) == -1 )
        return 1;

    return a.exec();
}
```

But I have the following error:

```
undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
```

The same code with the according reference compile ok with *SDL 1.2*.

Any idea?

Comment: Does SDL really work with QT?  Don't they both want control of the main event loop?

Comment: Can you state the contents of your SDL2 "lib" folder?

Comment: @japreiss One can use SDL with Qt just fine, as long as only either one of the two is used for windowing/event handling.

Comment: Your not linking to SDL properly. And I would advise against using both Qt and SDL together. Choose one or the other.

Comment: I must precise that this code works fine on MacOS and Qt (using the good path).

Comment: @Ancurio SDL2 lib folder contains libSDL2.a, libSDL2.dll.a, libSDL2.la, libSDL2_test.a, libSDL2main.a

Comment: and also a folder *pkgconfig* containing the file *sdl2.pc*

Comment: @Xonar What's wrong with the way I link SDL?

Comment: @MartinDelille If you don't link to SDL2 that's the error that you get. There's more than one folder in SDL2-2.0.1, are you linking to the correct library for your compiler? (bitness mismatch maybe)

Comment: exact! I used *SDL2-2.0.1\i686-w64-mingw32* instead of *SDL2-2.0.1\x86_64-w64-mingw32* and it worked! Post it as an answer if you want me to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted the answer as a comment, but in case someone in future has a similar problem here's the solution.

The error "undefined reference" means that there is a prototype that defined, but there is no definition to be found. Most commonly you are not linking to the library that has the definition.

In the authors case he was linking to a library meant for x86_64, but his target application was i686 so the linker couldn't find the reference for his target. Linking to the correct library for his target solved his problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you use CMake:

```
target_link_libraries(__YOUR_APPNAME__ PRIVATE SDL2)
```

It is just easy as that.

[More about target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html)